# Surface area of cylindrical surface using double integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, area

The formula for the surface area of a cylindrical surface is given by the equation
$$A(S) = \iint_D \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)^2}\;dA$$
This is the question I've been given:

> Find the surface area of the part of the cylindrical surface $x^2 + z^2 = 4$ that lies above the region $0 \leq x \leq 2$, $0 \leq y \leq x$.

I drew this diagram:

[image]

I’ve got two key questions:

1. Can someone help me understand the second limit? Because $x$ has a fixed upper limit, does this mean in this case $y$ will also $\to 2$? This was an assumption I made when drawing my diagram.
2. My cylinder function is not in the form $z = x^2 + y^2$, how will this change my application of the surface area formula? Should I rearrange to get it in this form: $z = x^2 + y^2$?

I tried this and worked through to get an incorrect answer: 
$$z = \sqrt{4-x^2}$$
where
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = -\frac{x}{\sqrt{4-x^2}} \qquad \text{and} \qquad \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = 0.$$

Comment: Welcome to Math S.E. You can make your question self-contained by presenting some equations in your question using $\LaTeX$. You may refer to [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/146687) to learn it.